# Usage of the preposition "to" after the noun "technique"

Tags: prepositions

"Military Technique **to** falling asleep in 2 minutes." (an article on Yahoo)

I would have thought there should be "...technique of falling asleep..." or "...technique for falling asleep...".

What is the grammatical explanation of using "to" here?

Answer (score 1):

The author seems to use "to" in order to indicate the purpose or result of the military technique. Looking through [Merriam-Webster's definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to), I think that this one is closest:

> —used as a function word to indicate purpose, intention, tendency, result, or end
> // came to our aid
> // drink to his health

Nevertheless, I agree with you that this doesn't sound very good. I would prefer to use an infinitive verb:

> military technique to fall asleep in 2 minutes

However, I think that the best version is your second option:

> military technique for falling asleep in 2 minutes

I probably wouldn't use the preposition "of" here; it has a somewhat different meaning.

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpful. It would be interesting for me to know what meaning may the using of "of" accrue to this sentence?

Comment: "Of" can be used simply to describe an item. For example, the "process of elimination" is a process that involves elimination. Similarly, "military technique of falling asleep" means that the military technique involves falling asleep; it doesn't necessarily indicate that that is its purpose or goal.

Comment: Very interesting implication. I wouldn't definitely have thought about it.